# Show rows only if previous measure member meets certain condition

Tags: sql-server, mdx

Consider certain query in MDX

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Income]} ON COLUMNS,
{
            SellDate.[year].Members
} ON ROWS
FROM [HD Kawiarnia]
```

that shows income of a company during each year. The question is how to show only this years in which income was higher then it was in the previous year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MyMeasure] as 
IIF(
([Measures].[Income], [SellDate].[Year].currentmember) 
     <= ([Measures].[Income], [SellDate].[Year].CURRENTMEMBER.PREVMEMBER) 
, NULL, 
[Measures].[Income])

SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Income]} on COLUMNS
NON EMPTY {[SellDate].[Year].CHILDREN} on ROWS
FROM 
[HD Kawiarnia]
```

I used the [IIF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145994.aspx) function to to evaluate the clause and return null if the previous year income is higher. I got the previous year by using the [PREVMEMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144719.aspx) function. I also replaced your [SellDate].[Year].MEMBERS with [SellDate].[Year].CHILDREN.  This removes the ALL member, which you probably didn't want to be returned.

Word of caution: although Iif is the simplest way to understand how to do this, it traditionally is a bit slow (although performance has improved with 2008 and 2012 versions of SQL Server). This one probably won't be too bad, but in general you can replace [iif functions with scripting using scope](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DustinRyan/bidn-blog/2636/top-3-simplest-ways-to-improve-your-mdx-query) to get better performance.